# Can someone please tell me the name of this Flower???

Tags: flowers

[image]

Can someone tell me the name of this flower please.
Please and Thank you!!

Answer (score 8):

It is a Hemerocallis - A day lily Cultivar. It is however a member of the Lilliacae family, hence the similarity. There are wide number of cultivars available. Found I think, originally I North America.

Comment: This is the common variety found all around the Midwest of the USA. I also have some here in Connecticut.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like an orange lily or [lilium bulbiferum](http://www.pfaf.org/user/plant.aspx?latinname=Lilium+bulbiferum)

Comment: The petals of the orange lily appear shorter, tapering to a thin petiole (or something like) whereas the flower in question appears to be long and straight petals.